# Lint to ensure method B is called after method A

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-lint

**Background:**
I am working on a resource extensive operation and reinitialising the object is too costly operation. So the current implementation involves following steps

`Initialisation -> Usage -> Cleanup`

Say my code is something like

```
public class A {

    public A(){
        //perform resource extensive operations
    }

    public A performTask(){
        //task performed
        return this;
    }

    public void saveChanges(){
        //perform commits and save changes
        //cleanup resource
        //perform other minor tasks
    }
}
```

**Requirement:**
Now how to inform the person using this class to call `saveChanges()` method after calling `performTask()`. Please note that `performTask()` is a dummy reference in this example, and in actual code it can be called multiple times.

Best example for my use case Android Shared Preference Editor. If I don't call `commit()` or `apply()` after calling `edit()` I get a warning like below

> SharedPreferences.edit() called without a corresponding commit() or apply()

So how can I create a warning something like above, To make sure `saveChanges()` is called after `performTask()`?

Comment: Why are you not calling saveChanges() in the body of performTask() itself? Is it the case that saveChanges() must be called after a certain number of performTask() calls?

Comment: @Solace yes, multiple calls will be made to performTask based on API response before calling save changes.